# Does anybody know car-hire small companies in Paris that accept debit cards?

Tags: car-rentals, paris

I want to rent a car in Paris and I was wondering if anybody knows any small car rental company. I'm thinking my chances to rent one without a credit card (I only hold a VISA debit card) are better than with a big company like Sixt or Hertz.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you have problems at big companies with your debit card? I didn't think anybody outside the US cared about credit vs. debit, as long as it's a Visa.

Comment: @fkraiem it's the first time I'm trying to rent a car. My concern comes from the fact that mostly all car rental companies specify in their payment terms that no debit cards are accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Hertz does allow you to use debit cards per their website policy, you will just be subject to a credit check:

> At most Hertz locations, debit cards (sometimes called check cards)
>   issued under a VISA or Mastercard logo which draw funds directly from
>   the cardholder's account may be used to qualify for rental. However,
>   prepaid or stored value cards which have a VISA or Mastercard logo are
>   not accepted to qualify for rental. When a debit card is accepted as
>   form of payment, at the start of the rental, two (2) forms of
>   identification must be presented. Debit Cards must have available
>   funds for the estimated amount of the rental charges and any
>   additional charges that may be incurred. Both debit cards and prepaid
>   or stored value cards issued under a VISA or Mastercard logo may be
>   used as a form of payment when you return the vehicle.
>
> For credit check information when using a Debit Card [click here](https://hertzhelp.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1007).